# Is "%n" correct as a newline using printf in Java?

Tags: java, string, printf, newline

I'm new to Java and I'm at my wits' end.

I have got my program to work, but I need help with the formatting when printing out.

```
if(count == 3)
    System.out.printf ("%-15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %n", n, " is compatible with ",dates[k],dates[k+1],dates[k+2]);
```

My output is:

```
Stacey Francis   is compatible with     Owen Farrell   Jack Clifford  Joshua Watkins
```

I would like my output to be (without repeating stacey francis name or "is compatible with":

```
Stacey Francis   is compatible with  Owen Farrell
                                 
                          Jack Clifford
                                 
                          Joshua Watkins
```

Just wondering how to go about this?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, `%n` is a newline in printf. See the documentation of [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), specifically the conversion table which specifies:

> '`n`'     line separator  The result is the platform-specific line separator

Your output currently only has a linebreak at the end, not at the points that you seem to want them. You would need to use a format like:

```
"%-15s %15s %15s %n %15s %n %15s %n"
```

(and maybe some tabs thrown in there for alignment).

Answer (score 11):

`%n` should have worked. But the problem is, you have just used it at the end in your format string. You need to insert it at appropriate places: -

```
"%-15s %15s %15s %n %45s %n %45s"
```

---

You can also use `"\n"` between your format specifiers to print a newline: -

```
System.out.printf ("%-15s %15s %15s \n %45s \n %45s", 
                     n, " is compatible with ", dates[k],dates[k+1],dates[k+2]);
```

Also, I have increased the `length` of last two names from `15` to `45`, to format them just below the previous names.

Comment: Doesn't `%n` tell the compiler to go to `System.getProperty("line.separator")` which supposed to be a new line?

Comment: Hey Rohit,  I tried and it doesn't even print out her name or who she is compatible with at all.

Comment: @Maroun85.. Yeah you are right. Forgot that. Re-checked the OP to get what exactly he got wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @BethAnnMeredith.. I think it should work. Can you post what you tried? May be you missed somthing.

Comment: @BethAnnMeredith.. Do remember to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides it.

Comment: Don't use \n, %n is safer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31981167/11211041

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (count == 3) {
    System.out.printf("%-15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %n", n, " is compatible with",
            dates[k],dates[k+1],dates[k+2]+"\n");
}
```