# Separate elements of list durint printf in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, printf, formatter

I have a list *cars* and I want to write it into a new file using the Formatter, but when I am going to use the printf, I don't know what to do to obtain the desired output

```
public static void Write() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
        x.format(cars.get(i).toString(), " ");

    }
    System.out.println("A new file has been created");
}
```

What should I add where the %n is, in order to get all the elements (i) printed in a new line?

Comment: What is `x` in your example?

Comment: @talex public static x = new Formatter;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking a new line using printf in java? Is %n correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510661/taking-a-new-line-using-printf-in-java-is-n-correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `Formatter.format` wrong.

First argument should be format string, rest are object used in substitution.

In your case you have to use

```
 x.format("%s%n", cars.get(i).toString());
```

where

- `%s` is placeholder for first argument
- `%n` will be replaced to platform specific line separator.

Javadoc for this method describe format of "format" string in great details.